# How to implement multiple redirects using PHP and/or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I want to log out of multiple websites on a click on a logout button. The websites reside on different domains. I tried making AJAX calls to the logout URLS of those website but faced a lot of CORS issues.

Is there a way by which I can redirect from one logout URL to another? I don't have much control over the code on other websites. Is there a way to implement the following using PHP and/or JavaScript?

> User Clicks Logout -> Logout from website1 -> Redirects to Website2 -> Logout from Website2 -> .... -> return to home page website1.

The user should click logout once.

I tried the following code which gives CORS error:

```
          $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.website1.com/logout",
        type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'json',
      headers: { 'api-key':'myKey' },
        success: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
          console.log('DP7 Logout Status: ' + xhr.status);
        },
        error: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
          console.log(textStatus);
          alert('Logout unsuccessful! Please try again');
        }
      }).done(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://www.website2.com/logout",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log('DP8 Logout Status: ' + xhr.status);
          },
          error: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            alert('Logout unsuccessful! Please try again');
          }
        }).done(function() {
          $('#logout').hide();
          console.log('Logout Successful');
          console.log('Redirect to home page will occur now');
          //Add redirect to home page here!
    
        });//EOF DP7 logout
      }); //EOF DONE
```

Comment: and `return to home page of my website` is home page website 3 or website2/website1?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile website1. Made the correction in the question as well.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless it is some kind of browser plugin.

Comment: The user signed in on all these site? or when they signed in on site 1 they auto signin on site 2 and 3? and how do u log users out on site 1?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile It's an assumption that the user is signed into the websites

Comment: What is the problem if you call logout of the sites by ajax?

Comment: @AmirZojaji OP already said CORS issues.

Comment: @AmirZojaji **Same origin policy**

Comment: I didn't understand the meaning of CORS issues.

Comment: @Arihant do u mind showing the code u did first that did not work due to CORS issues

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile added the code to the question